# Did I earn the Organizer without deserving it?

Tags: bug, tag-badges

It seems I've earned the Organizer badge without deserving it.

[image]

I've edited [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319777/in-a-column-find-all-cells-with-same-text-inside-then-sum-all-the-values-in-th) by mainly inserting the picture that was simply referred by the OP.

While I was editing the question I've been notified that another edit was on-going; it was the edit made by @Alessandro who actually edited the question's tag.

[image]

It seems, therefore, that I've somehow "inherited" the Organizer badge.

Could this be a bug in the badge assignement process?

Comment: If anything this is a "bug" concerning edit conflicts, but your edit did actually change the tags.  So in that regard you deserve the badge.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thank you for your comment. So, also considering the answer of Servy, I've got a badge for having done the wrong thing. Not so proud about that.

Comment: Just make it up by making more-meaningful contributions.

Comment: I'll do my best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a bug.  You changed the tags of the question.  You didn't *intend* to, and your change was harmful, but you did do it.

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer; so I've got a badge for a harmful action: not so proud about that. It should be removed.

Comment: @il_raffa You seem to give *way* too much weight to the importance of the badge.  The badge says that you edited the tags of one post.  It doesn't mean you did a good job of it, and as a consequence, nobody is going to think better of just just because you have this badge, nobody will care either way.